# Django: can't trigger AJAX call and send values back to my form

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I need to run an AJAX call to perform a quick calculation in my django view and return the result in my html page, inside a  tag.

I'm very new to Javascript so I don't understand why my AJAX call hasn't been triggered. This is my html and JS code:

```
<input type="text" name="SHm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">
<input type="text" name="STm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">

<button id="estimation" name= "estimation" onclick="calculate()">Estimation</button>
<span>{{estimation}}</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculate () {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/myApp/templates/homepage/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              SHm2: $('#SHm2').val(),
              STm2: $('#STm2').val()
            },
            success: function(estimation) {
            alert(estimation);
            document.getElementById("estimation").innerHTML = estimation;

            }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax and 'estimation' in request.POST:
        SHm2 = request.POST.get('SHm2')
        STm2 = request.POST.get('STm2')
        estimation = float(SHm2) + float(STm2)
        estimation = json.dumps(estimation)
        return HttpResponse(estimation, content_type='application/json')
```

The problem is that the AJAX code isn't triggered since I don't receive the alert. Nevertheless, the code in my django view is running anyway (which is strange, since I specified to run if 'request.is_ajax', which doesn't seem to be recognized on the other hand). It loads a new page where it correctly displays the result. But it's not what I want since I need the result to be in my form within the span tag where {{estimation}} is my variable.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE:
Thanks to your answers, it's getting better. I've replaced in views.py 'request.is_ajax' by 'request.is_ajax()'. I've added the 'id' attribute to my input boxes. This helped me to trigger the AJAX call and not to load stuff in a new page. There is one last thing though. I'm still not able to display in my span tag the value of the estimation variable. I realised that it had no 'id' attribute so I did the following change:

```
<span id="estimation2">{{estimation}}</span>
```

Also in my JS code, I replaced in the success part the last line to:

```
document.getElementById("estimation2").innerHTML = estimation;
```

Basically I replaced "estimation" by "estimation2".

Unfortunately the span tag is not updated. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: in your `ajax` request url, you are passing the path to the homepage template. You should pass the url for homepage route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the issue came from the fact that I didn't declare the type of my button in my html code. The default value (i.e. "submit") prevented it from triggering my AJAX code as needed. So in the end I had to set it to 'type="button"' to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Change name to id. because #means id of the field. Like from **name="SHm2"** to **id="SHm2"**

```
<input type="text" id="SHm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">
<input type="text" id="STm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">

<button id="estimation" name= "estimation" onclick="calculate()">Estimation</button>
<span>{{estimation}}</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculate () {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/myApp/templates/homepage/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              SHm2: $('#SHm2').val(),
              STm2: $('#STm2').val()
            },
            success: function(estimation) {
            alert(estimation);
            document.getElementById("estimation").innerHTML = estimation;

            }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. Any idea what else is wrong?

Comment: Html and ajax works fine. you have to check your Django code. try to remove these extra condition  **request.is_ajax and 'estimation' in request.POST:**

Answer (score 1):

1st

`request.is_ajax` is a function

2nd

`'estimation' in request.POST`
You have it in your statement but you did not pass it to view. Add it to `data` or remove from statement

Comment: Ok, thanks; so I added 'estimation' in the 'data' part of my JS  code and it definitely helped since I'm now receiving the alert with the right result. Nevertheless, after the alert, it loads a new page rather than writing the result on my form. Any idea why? Also, I'm not really sure what I should be doing with request.is_ajax. Could you please be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: @curiousIT ```request.is_ajax()```. And I have no idea wht it loads a new page. You have no such thing in code you provided

Comment: Things are getting much better. Now I just need to retrieve the 'estimation' value. I've provided a new update in the original question. I hope it helps.